# Vue Chart.js - simple dot/line on bar chart

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'd need to add a simple dot/vertical line on my `bar` chart that has a dynamical X value, and 0 for Y value. Preview of what I need (the red dot):

[image]

Where the green values are dynamic.

Preview of my current state:

[image]

**Where 3.30** should be the X coordinate of the dot - [3.30, 0].

I'm using [Vue chart](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs) for the charts and I tried do create a [mixed](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html) one with the `bar` and `scatter` but `scatter` requires `type: 'linear'` for it's `xAxis` which doesn't suit my need for the `bar` chart.

So I tried with [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) and it's `box` type which accepts "coordinates" but the problem here is that the `X` value **must be a fixed value on the X axis** (`labels` object). If I put for the X axis [3,0] it will work, but if there is a decimal number, like [3.5, 0], it won't work.

---

```
  // data
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 1,
          stepSize: 0.1
        }
      }]
    }
  }

  // computed 
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], // fixed value, there are always 6 bars
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Values',
      backgroundColor: '#f89098',
      data: this.tableInputValues // array of decimal values
    }
  ]
```

---

So, my question is how to put a "simple" dot, or a vertical line, on a *Chart.js* bar chart where the dot has a dynamical value for the X axis -> [dynamic value, 0].

FYI - it's about [Expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cn6zywvm/). So now let's say would like to have a dot on the xAxis, or a vertical line where the xAxes value is dynamic (like 3.9, or 2.75).

Comment: @Vucko, Hi, can you describe your problem, such as what data x-axis and y-axis used to describe? Example in your snapshot, x-axis used to describe the values and y-axis used for frequency (0.0 to 1.0), but in your fiddle, x-axis is not related to   your problem. And what data, which the dot in x-axis you want to show, describe for? I think you can use `type: 'buddle'` with mixed type for your problem, but I hope the detail description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand Vue Chart works using canvas (as seen on [Demo page](http://demo.vue-chartjs.org/)).
So, my suggestion here is to retrieve the canvas node representing the chart in your DOM and dynamically write the desired dot. For example:

```
var c = document.getElementById("bar-chart");   //hereby assuming canvas named "bar-chart"
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";                     //red color for the dot
ctx.beginPath();
let yPosition = c.height - 5;                 //fixed y position
let xPosition = 35;                          //that's the dynamic expected value
ctx.arc(xPosition, yPosition, 2.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJXVRx) you find a demo showing how to achieve that using Vue. In this scenario, you need to wrap the code to draw a dot on the canvas in a `afterDraw` hook. This hook needs to be attached to the chart component as a plugin, so like this:

```
...
mounted () { 
   //adding the plugin to draw the red dot
   this.addPlugin({
    id: 'chart-plugin',
    afterDraw: function (chart) {
       var c = chart.canvas;   
       var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";                     
       ctx.beginPath();
       let xPosition = 742; //x positioning to be calculated according to your needs
       let yPosition = c.height - 28;                                       
       ctx.arc(xPosition, yPosition, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
       ctx.fill();
    }
  });

  //actual chart rendering
  this.renderChart({ 
    ...
  });
}
...
```

For the sake of completeness, [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) you find the list of all the available hooks of Chart.js plugin API.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you modify the answer for a Vue solution. Thanks

Comment: @Vucko here you go.

Comment: Tnx for the update, I'll let you know when I test it.

Comment: @Vucko you're welcome. Here you find your JsFiddle example updated with the afterDraw hook: https://jsfiddle.net/jh4aobw8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, can you also modify for using [vue-chart](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#custom-new-charts) plugin, it'll help.

Comment: @Vucko you are welcome. The example with the vue-chart plugin is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJXVRx

Comment: Nice! Tnx for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution for your problem https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/e54djwxp/

And this is screenshot for the result

[image]

In my solution, I use `type="line"` and both x-axis and y-axis with `type="linear"`. I also add property `options` to `<chart>` for using `options` in `ChartJS`

```
<div id="vue">
  <chart type="line" :data="data" :options="options"></chart>
</div>
```

The `options` will set-up x-axis and y-axis to render the data points and expected value:

```
      options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            ticks: {
                min: 1,
                max: 6,
                stepSize: 1
            }
          }],
           yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                stepSize: 0.1
            }
            }]
        }
      }
```

And the `data` will have 2 `datasets`. The first is data points, use type `line`, and the second is the expected value which use type `bubble`.

```
      data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Frequency Data',
            data: dataPoints.map(({ val, freq }) => ({
                x: val,
              y: freq
            })),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(72, 202, 59, 0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(72, 202, 59, 1)'
        }, {
            label: 'Expected Value',
            type: 'bubble',
            data: [{ 
                x: expectedValue, 
              y: 0, 
              r: 8 // radius
            }],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 68, 0, 0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 68, 0, 1)'
        }]
        },
```

In `datasets`, we have `dataPoints` and `expectedValue`, it will be fetched from API to get your data points. I also simulate the simple API for data points:

```
// simulate the API to get data points
const retrieveData = () => [
    { val: 1, freq: 0.15 },
    { val: 2, freq: 0.25 },
    { val: 3, freq: 0.3 },
    { val: 4, freq: 0.2 },
    { val: 5, freq: 0.1 },
    { val: 6, freq: 0.45 }
]


// fetch your data here, return array of JSON { val, freg }
const dataPoints = retrieveData() || [];

// calculate expected value = sum( val * freq ) each i in dataPoints
const expectedValue = dataPoints.reduce((cur, { val, freq }) => cur + val * freq, 0).toFixed(4);
```

You can run snippet or run on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/e54djwxp/92/

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/e54djwxp/92/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer, really nice solution.

Comment: what package is this ?